# Is it possible to run accelerometer of iPhone in background?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

I want to use accelerometer of iPhone to get the log file of accelerometer value (maybe for 24 hours). Is it possible to let accelerometer runs in background while other applications are running?

Answer (score 13):

You can do it now, if your app is allowed to run in the background for other reasons. See the Core Motion API's `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:).

Comment: You beauty, that is what I was looking for. YES YOU CAN PROCESS accelerometer in the background.  Google startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler will show you that the phone will queue up the acceleration data and then send it to a handler function to process at regular intervals.

Comment: using the startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue: handler we can get the accelerometer updates in the first 10 min after app eneters to background. HOw to get the updates continuously.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it is not. You basically can't run anything but a music app in the background.

You can run the accelerometer while the phone is suspended though.

See this blog for how to do it: http://marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/

I use this technique in my GPS recording app.

Comment: Are you using accelerometer in background? Can you tell me how you did it. I have downloaded the code and tried to call it in my class where I am getting accelerometer data. The file plays but accelerometer doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Andrew Johnson - does apple accept the playing silent sound through out the app in background also.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is presently not possible, at least if you want to distribute your application through the App Store.