# what are the setting we change in info.plist for background process?

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an iPhone application that I want to run in the background. Stack Overflow, tell me, what do I have to change in the application's *info.plist*?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not very familiar with this technology. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run accelerometer of iphone in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294985/is-it-possible-to-run-accelerometer-of-iphone-in-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do nothing for this. ios 4.0 and later provide this functionality by default and you cant do any thing with lower one.

Comment: Sir,is there any possibility for finding the x,y,z axis values in the background.

Comment: What do you mean by background. Background thread within the app or whole app in background

Comment: I dont think so, but when you come from background then you need to find the x,y and z axis values.use this method - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: or this method - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: I want to find out the axis values when the application is went to background.

Comment: ok then use - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application    or   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: In that i use the uiacceleration for finding the x,y,z axis values.But it gives the result as 0 for x,y,z

Comment: Then you need to check your accelerometer methods.

Comment: That methods are not fired when the application is in background.

Comment: humm that will not call when your app is in background what you need you need to store the coordinates in NSUserDefaults when your control reach in - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application method.(at this time your app is going in background but still in foreground).make global variable for showing x,y and z and each time save values in it. then you can access these variables in applicationWillResignActive method, now here you can save these in user defaults for further use.Hope you can understand what i am trying to describe.

Comment: Ok.we save that values in the userdefaults.And next one is compare that values every time with device x,y,z axis values.

Comment: dont save these values in user defaults each time save when you are going in background.when you are foreground you can use the class level variables.

Comment: But in background uiaccelerometer delegate method was not fired for getting the x,y,z axis values

Answer (score 1):

You can set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` as `false`in your info.plist to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Sir,after entering to background,is ther any possibility for finding the x,y,z axis values in the background.

Comment: Once your application enter into background state it is actually moved to the suspended state shortly thereafter. While in this state, the application does not execute any code and may be removed from memory at any time.So inorder to get any value while your application is in background needs some types of background execution & this must be declared in advance by the application that uses them.You can refer this:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6.

Comment: UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is not available in info.plist

Comment: Right click upon info.plist & Open it in xml format.Now write & save <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<false/>

Comment: Now after saving this will show as "Application does not run in background" followed by an empty checkbox.

Comment: s.it shows.If we check then application is not running in the background.am i correct

Comment: Yes, if you checkmark this checkbox or <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key> <true/> then your application do not run in background.

Comment: how much time the application can run on background

Comment: You can't run an application in the background for an indefinite time.You can refer to previously mentioned URL to check what kind of application has such permission.

Comment: So we cant run any application in the background.Only that url specified applications can run on background.Am i correct

Comment: Just refer the previous mentioned URL for more details.

Comment: Yes, if you want to launch your application in appstore ;)

Answer (score 0):

In info.plist add a new tag by clicking the plus symbol. It lists you all the other options you have. There you will have "Application does not run in background". Check or uncheck on the box as you need. So that it allows or doesn't allows your app to run in background.

Comment: Sir is ther any possibility for finding the x,y,z axis values in the background.

Comment: This is for prevent the app to run in background not run the app from background.

Comment: Yes, its possible. You can use an image or label to check. Use CGPoint or mouse drag options to find out the axis values.

Comment: I want to find out the device x,y,z axis values